# nginx + MySQL + php5 + Wordpress: Too much php5-fpm processes

Tags: mysql, nginx, wordpress, php5, www-data

I have this web server running on nginx + MySQL + php5 + Wordpress. The thing is, the server is to slow and I think it's due to the number of php5-fpm running.

Look at the numbers of php5-fpm processes I have. It's too much! The server can't handle that much (I think). How do I decrease the number of processes?

```
top - 18:38:26 up  2:45,  3 users,  load average: 59.34, 47.33, 25.20
Mem:    498320k total,   492616k used,     5704k free,      484k buffers
Swap:  2096124k total,  2064080k used,    32044k free,    12772k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  719 root      20   0     0    0    0 D    0  0.0   1:01.73 kswapd0
11242 www-data  20   0  318m 5240  552 D    0  1.1   0:11.12 php5-fpm
11239 www-data  20   0  318m 5424   88 D   10  1.1   0:10.37 php5-fpm
11250 www-data  20   0  315m 4692  500 D    0  0.9   0:10.16 php5-fpm
11245 www-data  20   0  320m 5020   40 D    0  1.0   0:09.60 php5-fpm
11241 www-data  20   0  319m 5148   56 D   10  1.0   0:09.29 php5-fpm
 3233 root      20   0 58688 1120  736 D    0  0.2   0:09.27 vmtoolsd
11256 www-data  20   0  318m 5272   76 D    0  1.1   0:08.93 php5-fpm
11247 www-data  20   0  318m 5648   48 D    0  1.1   0:08.73 php5-fpm
11251 www-data  20   0  314m 4312  316 D    0  0.9   0:08.63 php5-fpm
14751 www-data  20   0  315m 4240   76 D    0  0.9   0:08.25 php5-fpm
11244 www-data  20   0  318m 5056   48 D    0  1.0   0:07.83 php5-fpm
14967 mysql     20   0  252m 8328    0 S    2  1.7   0:07.81 mysqld
14817 www-data  20   0  307m 4616   36 D    0  0.9   0:07.79 php5-fpm
14758 www-data  20   0  307m 4580   16 D    0  0.9   0:07.70 php5-fpm
14786 www-data  20   0  307m 4076   20 D    0  0.8   0:07.29 php5-fpm
11243 www-data  20   0  318m 6896  104 D    0  1.4   0:07.16 php5-fpm
11252 www-data  20   0  310m 4532   68 D    0  0.9   0:07.01 php5-fpm
11255 www-data  20   0  318m 5028   88 D    0  1.0   0:06.79 php5-fpm
14761 www-data  20   0  308m 4688   16 D    0  0.9   0:06.46 php5-fpm
14834 www-data  20   0  306m 4760  404 D    0  1.0   0:06.39 php5-fpm
14757 www-data  20   0  307m 4340   20 D    0  0.9   0:06.34 php5-fpm
14762 www-data  20   0  307m 4068   20 D    0  0.8   0:06.27 php5-fpm
    1 root      20   0 23760    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:06.18 init
11240 www-data  20   0  318m 5868   72 D    0  1.2   0:06.01 php5-fpm
11249 www-data  20   0  319m 4908  544 D    0  1.0   0:05.94 php5-fpm
14825 www-data  20   0  305m 6368  648 D    0  1.3   0:05.69 php5-fpm
11246 www-data  20   0  313m 3984   40 D    0  0.8   0:05.11 php5-fpm
14812 www-data  20   0  307m 4084   20 D   10  0.8   0:05.08 php5-fpm
 3274 bind      20   0  213m    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.70 named
14827 www-data  20   0  305m 7000  604 D    0  1.4   0:04.62 php5-fpm
14832 www-data  20   0  307m 3768  100 D    0  0.8   0:04.50 php5-fpm
14872 www-data  20   0  295m 6124  756 D    0  1.2   0:04.45 php5-fpm
  845 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.21 kworker/3:1
14769 www-data  20   0  309m 9472   16 D   10  1.9   0:03.71 php5-fpm
14755 www-data  20   0  307m 4056   20 D    0  0.8   0:03.53 php5-fpm
14823 www-data  20   0  307m 4256   36 D    0  0.9   0:03.47 php5-fpm
14833 www-data  20   0  307m 4764  688 D    0  1.0   0:03.29 php5-fpm
14818 www-data  20   0  307m 4628   36 D    0  0.9   0:03.17 php5-fpm
14884 www-data  20   0  267m  11m  692 D    0  2.4   0:03.03 php5-fpm
14697 www-data  20   0 30840  540  312 S    0  0.1   0:02.59 nginx
14936 www-data  20   0  276m 8420  572 D    0  1.7   0:02.34 php5-fpm
14696 www-data  20   0 30868  228    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.29 nginx
14820 www-data  20   0  307m 4728   36 D    0  0.9   0:02.02 php5-fpm
14882 www-data  20   0  276m   9m  628 D    0  2.1   0:02.00 php5-fpm
14815 www-data  20   0  306m 4300   44 D    0  0.9   0:01.92 php5-fpm
14693 www-data  20   0 30736  416  188 S    0  0.1   0:01.63 nginx
14698 root      20   0 19268  504  180 R    0  0.1   0:01.62 top
15143 www-data  20   0  257m 4524  176 S    0  0.9   0:01.60 php5-fpm
14695 www-data  20   0 30872  648  372 S    0  0.1   0:01.59 nginx
15149 root      20   0 33712  920  408 S    0  0.2   0:01.52 mysql
14694 www-data  20   0 30840  360  108 S    0  0.1   0:01.28 nginx
14883 www-data  20   0  263m 6332  652 D    0  1.3   0:01.27 php5-fpm
11236 root      20   0  253m  304  172 S    0  0.1   0:01.25 php5-fpm
14935 www-data  20   0  276m 8500  272 D    0  1.7   0:01.09 php5-fpm
14939 www-data  20   0  257m 2968  108 S    0  0.6   0:01.07 php5-fpm
14934 www-data  20   0  276m 7996  612 D    0  1.6   0:00.97 php5-fpm
  788 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.91 kworker/2:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have configured php5-fpm, you need to look at the max_children setting.

Comment: This is my /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf: http://www.pastebin.com/YWfBve32 /////// and here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: http://www.pastebin.com/ttgjQe34 ////// The website is at http://www.casamento10.com ///////// As you can see above, I've made some changes but now the site is not even loading. HALP!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to `S` column, you will see that almost of them are in `"D" state` (uninterruptible sleep). Are there any special in the nginx log?

Comment: Can I filter the only active processes? See only those that are actually consuming any memory and are not at a sleep state?

Comment: Notice that this is `D` - **uninterruptible** sleep, it is different from `S` - interruptible sleep. You can filter all the running or runable processes with `ps -eo pid,user,state,comm | awk '$4 == "php5-fpm" && $3 == "R" { print $0 }'`.